# How to fix zipfile read error in Colaboratory?

Tags: python-3.x

While extracting zipfile in to my google drive using colaboratory, I got an error saying zipfile read error. How to fix it?

I'm trying to unzip file using the following python 3 script:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

!unzip '/gdrive/My Drive/file.zip' -d '/gdrive/My Drive/Destination/'
```

After extracting 4 files from the zip I got this error

```
error:  zipfile read error
```

Comment: Im having the same problem. Did you ever solve this

Comment: Same issue, I'm extracting file from drive in colab local storage, after extracting 2628/10000 images, it causes zip file error and terminates. I tried various alternatives but no solution.

Comment: Encountered the same issue, unmounted and remounted drive worked for me

Comment: Any fix? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: August 2020, still having this problem with 25 GB zip file

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve the *why*, but was able to get put a band-aid on the problem (along with some process informatin) with the following Python code:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

# Get information about how much you're decompressing
zf = ZipFile('./gdrive/My Drive/poizon/data/images.zip')
uncompress_size = sum((file.file_size for file in zf.infolist()))
print('uncompressed_size',uncompress_size/1e6)

# Loop through all files attempting to decompress each individually
extracted_size = 0
for file in zf.infolist():
    extracted_size += file.file_size
    print ("%s %%" % (extracted_size * 100/uncompress_size))
    try:
      zf.extract(file)
    except:
      continue
```

Comment: Not really works. The error still occurs, decompressing slows down and stops

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import zipfile
import os

file_location = 'file_path/file_name.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(file_location, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('/content') # Replace '/content' with where you want to extract all files.
```

I hope it will not show any error.